# How can I respond to a right-click in an HTML table "cell" (td) in a Meteor project?

Tags: meteor

Assuming the following:

I have an HTML page that loads a template.
The template name is `scheduleTable`.
The template desrcribes an HTMLTable, with (of course) various `tr`s and `td`s, with a particular `td` that uses a CSS class named `"tddetails1"`

If I want to respond with JavaScript to a right-click on that `"tddetails1"` element, I would think I would need code something like this in the js file:

```
Template.scheduleTable.events({
    "right-click .tddetails1": function (event) {
    // do something 
  });
```

But what event can I use? There is no "right-click" event, and I don't want to capture "regular" (left) clicks. Am I doomed to use an html button in each `td`, and respond to their click events?

### UPDATE

Yes, Christian's answer was "spot on"; this works:

### HTML

```
<template name="tblExpenseDescription">
<table width="75%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="200px"><strong>Description of Expense</strong></td>
        <td class="rc1" >Date 1: <input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"/>            
        </td>
        . . .
```

### JavaScript

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.tblExpenseDescription.events({
    "mousedown .rc1": function (event) {
           if (event.button == 2) {
               console.log('date1 was right-clicked');
           }
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `mousedown` event handler and check that `event.button == 2`:

```js
Template.scheduleTable.events({
    "mousedown .tddetails1": function (event) {
         if (event.button == 2) {
             // this code will run on right-click
             // do something
         }
    }
});
```

EDIT:

To also prevent the context menu from popping up add:

```
"contextmenu .tddetails1": function (event) {
    return false;
}
```

into your event handler object.

Comment: It should be noted that the significance of using `return false` instead of `event.preventDefault()` is that `return false` is essentially doing three things: `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); return false`, whereas using `event.preventDefault()` and returning will not stop the event from bubbling up.